# UILabel with NSAttributedString returns incorrect boundingRect value

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, uilabel, nsattributedstring

```
func calculateSizeFor(label:UILabel, attributedText: NSAttributedString) -> CGSize {
    let constraint:CGSize = CGSize(width: label.frame.size.width,
                                   height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    let context:NSStringDrawingContext = NSStringDrawingContext()
    let boundingBox = attributedText.boundingRect(with: constraint,
                                                  options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin,
                                                            .usesFontLeading],
                                                  context: context)
    return boundingBox.size
}
```

The height value is always greater than the actual height, resulting in additional padding at the top and bottom edge of the `UILabel`. Whereas when I try to calculate boundingRect for plain text, value returned is always exact.

I need to pre-calculate the label height in order to display it as a `UICollectionViewCell` component.

Am I missing anything here? Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: I have a similar issue right now getting a wrong size(width and height). Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

same issue, there may be a '\n' at the end of the attr string,
caused by tags such as <p> I think,
solved by delete the last character:

```
let mattrStr: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: yourAttrStr)
if let lc = attrStr.string.last, lc == "\n" {
    mattrStr.deleteCharacters(in: NSRange(location: mattrStr.length - 1, length: 1))
}
```